# Lost in the Crystal Caves - Solve Step Order

Tags: my-little-pony-ccg

In the MLP CCG there is a problem card called "Lost in the Crystal Caves":
http://mlpccg.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_in_the_Crystal_Caves_(Canterlot_Nights)

If confronting the problem forces you to move a character from the problem back to home, and you would no longer satisfy the problem requirements, would you still score the point for initially confronting the problem?

What if your opponent was satisfying the problem? Would you perform a faceoff?

At what point does the problem text trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to be aware that "confront the problem" means having enough power at the problem when you enter the Confront Step. The specific rules (from the [Canterlot Nights comprehensive rules](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140509173956/mylittleponyccg/images/a/ab/MLP_CCG_Comprehensive_Rules_%28v2.0%29.pdf)) about this say:

> (611.1) The turn player confronts a Problem if that player meets the Problem’s confront requirements.
>
> (611.3) A player meets the confront requirements of a Problem if that player controls characters at that Problem contributing power in the required amounts of the required colors to confronting that Problem.
>
> (611.4) As a player confronts a Problem, that player scores a point. If an opponent also meets their confront requirements for that Problem (611.3), there will be a Problem Faceoff at that Problem.

When you enter the Confront Step, you check whether you have the confront requirements of the problem, and if you do, you confront the problem and get a point. The "As" wording in (611.4) indicates that confronting the problem and scoring a point are the same event, so the problem's triggered ability triggers on that event and happens after you get the point.

The second half of (611.4) says that there is a faceoff "if an opponent also meets their confront requirements". This doesn't say that the opponent confronts the problem, so the ability doesn't trigger for them. It also doesn't say you check your power at the problem again, so you move to faceoff depending on whether you *confronted* the problem, not whether you *currently* satisfy the confront requirements.

Comment: I was inclined to think that the point should be scored, but no faceoff performed if it got that far, but the language does seem to suggest otherwise. Thanks!